# Can CrystalReports for VS2013 be programmed to export each page of the report to a separate pdf file

Tags: pdf, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I am well into developing a billing program in VB2013 that needs to be able to export each customer bill to a pdf file that can then be attached to an email to the customer being billed. I have used CR for many, many years, but I have not found any way to programmatically make CR export to pdf. I have made activereports2 do so, but I am trying to get back down to just one report generator. I have had compatibility issues with Activereports2 by Datadynamics when running on some Windows Vista and later machines, so I was hoping to move everything to CR.

Comment: The process you are describing is known as bursting. Export should be done by group , not by page because there might be customers with data, which does not fit on one page. What is your question ? How to export to PDF or how to burst a report ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can definitely generate Crystal Reports and convert to PDF on the fly in .NET.

Here's some sample code to help with that (this saves the PDF to the database, but you can remove that part if you don't need it):

```
public static int Crystal_PDFToDatabase(string reportName, object par1, object par2, object par3, string user, string DocName, string DocDesc, string DocType, int ClaimID, string exportFormatType)
    {
        try
        {
            CrystalReportSource CrystalReportSource1 = Crystal_SetDataSource(reportName, par1, par2, par3);

            //SET EXPORT FORMAT
            CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType typ = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;

           Stream str = CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(typ);
            if (str != null)
            {
                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                str.CopyTo(memoryStream);

                int DocID = db_Docs.SaveNewDocument(DocName, DocDesc, DocType, user, memoryStream.ToArray(), ClaimID, null, null);
                return DocID;
            }

            //clear out cache (to prevent other crystal reports from reusing old generated documents 
            CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.Close();
            CrystalReportSource1.Dispose();

            return 0;
        }
        catch
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Now a separate issue is not produce a separate PDF for each page in the report. I simply would not design it that way. I'd instead have the Crystal report generate 1 page, convert to PDF memorystream on the fly, and email it out. Then iterate on to the next customer. So much easier that way instead of having to figure out how (if its possible at all) to split that one huge Crystal Report / PDF into many slices.

Comment: Thanks for this info, however I am a VB programmer. However, I have now, thanks mostly to your response, been able to get crystal reports to export pdf files, one per database record as I needed it to. My problem now is how to send emails to each customer with their pdf file attached. Crystal Reports does not seem to offer any way to attach a file to the emails they can create.

Comment: you wouldn't be using Crystal Report to do this. You would use an SMTP sender class